# How to install openjdk-9-jdk on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 18.04, when I launch

```
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk
```

I get the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-9-jdk
```

how do I install it correctly?

Thanks

Sergio

Comment: This is not programming related and thus off-topic for StackOverflow. this question might be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Or the [Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: I suggest using OpenJDK 10 as it replaces OpenJDK 9. In September Java 11 will replace them both.  I have found Java 11 EA it be better than Java 10 so far.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tested with Ubuntu 18.04 docker image:

It did not have a package openjdk-9-jdk it only provides openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-11-jdk. The 9 version is superseded by the 11 version (see http://jdk.java.net/9/). So it is recommended to use the openjdk-11-jdk if possible.

Check with:

`sudo apt-cache search openjdk`

If you really need the 9er version get it manually via http://jdk.java.net/archive/.

Comment: I reeally need version 9 of JAVA and the link on the site seems broken